# Pass " to cmd with escape \ p4v does not strip out the \ in c#

Tags: c#, cmd, perforce

I am trying to create a string to pass to cmd to have P4V create and label a file.  The problem is the when I pass the string to cmd the escape \ is seen as part of the file path and causing the file not to be found. Is there a way to pass a " without the \ ?

Here is the code I am using it generates a string in cmd as

```
p4 tag -l labelname \"c:\folder\filename\"
```

P4 needs the quotes outside the string.

Needed:

```
p4 tag -l labelname "c:\folder\filename"
```

```
             string tempString = @" """;
             tempString = tempString + stringToTest;
             stringToTest = tempString + @" """;

            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            proc.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
            proc.Arguments = @"/k p4 tag -l " + newLabel + " " + stringToTest;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);}enter code here
```

Any help appreciated.

Here the actual string that is passed to the process (proc.Arguments). I don't have Perforce on this machine so I can't show what is in cmd.exe.

"/k p4 tag -l labelname  \"c:\folder\filename \""

Comment: Output the string to console, debug output or file and then copy paste the real result into your question. Do not show us fake or retyped output. And put the string inside preformatted tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it a lot clearer when you compose strings using `String.Format`

```
proc.Arguments = string.Format("/k p4 tag -l {0} \"{1}\"",
                               "labelName", 
                               @"c:\folder\filename");
```

Comment: Thanks that helped.